# Input range current value

Tags: html

I am trying to render the current value of the current input range and I cannot render the previous one so if the slider goes back it does not show the current value while it's going back. My current approach is

```
<form name="registrationForm">
    <output name="ageOutputName" id="">24</output>
    <input type="range" name="ageInputName" id="ageInputId" value="24" min="1" max="100" oninput="ageOutputId.value = ageInputId.value">
    <output name="ageOutputName" id="ageOutputId">24</output>
</form>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1z6b2L0/)**

I'm trying to get the current value of `<input type="range">` into a `<output>` tag, but when I go to the left-hand side of the slider it fails to show the lower value but when I go to the right-hand side of the slider it works perfectly.

So what I am trying to achieve here is to increase the value of output tag when `input range` is increased while other output tag remains the same, and when the slider range is decreased then the other output tag should be as same as `input range` i.e. decreased value

Comment: This isn't quite clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Sorry, but I fear others may be thinking the same. Could you try to explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: @hmiedema9 fair enough, I've updated the question

Comment: The code in your fiddle seems to be working perfectly to me (checked in both safari and chrome) -- can you clarify what the problem is or how to reproduce it?

Comment: As noted by @DanielBeck, the code in the fiddle "works". I'm afraid you have to clarify exactly what the issue you are facing is.

Comment: @DanielBeck Sorry I added wrong fiddle, I've updated the question with correct fiddle

Comment: Can you *please* be specific about what it is you're trying to do here?  Your updated fiddle includes an extra `<output>` tag but doesn't try to do anything with it.  Are you trying to get the slider value to appear in both output fields? Or is the output display supposed to switch from one side to the other at some point in the range? (If, so, at what point should that happen? And what should happen to the other output field then?)   Something else?  We can't help you if you can't explain what you need help with!

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NeVmao , add another id to first one as well and assign value for that , oninput="ageOutputId.value = ageInputId.value;ageOutputId2.value = ageInputId.value;"

Comment: @DanielBeck So, as you pointed that extra `<output>` tag doesn't do anything, but when the slider is moved towards that slider that `<output>` tag should show the decreased value and the `<output>` tag on the right side should remain the same i.e. increase value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can piece together from your comments, I gather the intention here is that when the slider moves to the right, the `output` on the right-hand side should show the current value; when it moves to the left, the `output` on the left-hand side should show the current value.

Since you want different behavior depending on whether the slider value is increasing or decreasing, you'll need to keep the previous value around so you have something to compare it to.

Further explanation in comments below:

```js
// capture the initial value (as a number, not a string)
let prevValue = Number(ageInputId.value); 
// init both outputs:
ageOutputIncrease.value = prevValue;
ageOutputDecrease.value = prevValue

const showValue = function() {
  let newValue = Number(ageInputId.value);
  if (newValue > prevValue) {
    // slider is moving to the right
    ageOutputIncrease.value = newValue;
    // ageOutputDecrease.value = '';
  } else {
    // slider is moving to the left
    ageOutputDecrease.value = newValue;
    // ageOutputIncrease.value = '';
  }

  prevValue = newValue; // update prevValue for the next time
}
```

```css
/* I set a fixed width on the outputs; otherwise the slider 
   itself moves around when the values change */
output {display:inline-block; width: 1.5em;}
```

```html
<form name="registrationForm">
  <output id="ageOutputDecrease"></output>
  <input type="range" name="ageInputName" id="ageInputId" value="24" min="1" max="100" oninput="showValue()">
  <output id="ageOutputIncrease">24</output>
</form>
```

Comment: "I've also assumed you want to clear the value from the not-currently-in-use" you're right that's not the case, sorry for hassle and thank you for this solution :)

Comment: OK, I went ahead and removed that from the answer.  (Personally this seems like a rather confusing UI, but as that's not really the subject here I'll leave that be)

Comment: I'll take your word for it, it is a confusing UI, I was thinking something else initially, but I  had  to use this